# Unable to start Hadoop Tools start-all.sh showing nothing

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

Freshly installed Hadoop 3.3 version on Mac system and trying a simple standalone system. And was trying to start all the services but i see there is no logs from the system.

[image]

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Tried with Java 1.8 and Java 11 the output of start-all.sh remains same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ZSH, but the environment variable was pointing to a different JAVA environment. So have to update my .zsh with JAVA_HOME value to Java8 in the last line in the .zsh file.